# upload image with username from android to server using multipart post

Tags: android

i want to upload an image and the username from my android application to my server. i developped this code.
in my database i find the image without username ( value 0).i think that i should use the asynctask but i have no idea how to make it. i want to use this method if it's possible.

this is my code:

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    String fileName = sourceFileUri;
    String ref_name = "toto";

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + imagePath);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("image", fileName);
          conn.setRequestProperty("ref_name",ref_name);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\";filename="+ fileName + ";ref_name=" + ref_name+ ""+lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "+ serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    // Toast.makeText(New_annonce_act_step3.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                    + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

   // int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

}

```
Server code:private function do_upload()
{
    $type = explode('.', $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $type = strtolower($type[count($type)-1]);

    $img=uniqid(rand()).'.'.$type; 
                        $url = "./images/".$img;


    if(in_array($type, array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png")))
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]))
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],$url))

                return $img;

    return "";
}
```

for this code: i don't know if i should post only the image or the image and the username. that why i make 2 codes.

```
    public function save_image_relation_post(){
    $ref_name = $_POST["ref_name"];

    $url = $this->do_upload();
    $this->Images_model->save_image($ref_name, $url);
}
```

function with post image only:

```
public function save_image_test_post(){
 $url= $this->do_upload();
  $this->Images_model->save_image_test($url);
   }
```

Comment: sorry i change it. i just post it all if anyone need it

Comment: What kind of server do you use? Doesn't it send back a html page or other info? I see you open an input stream but are not using it. You should read the response from the server.

Comment: `upload an image and the username`. Ok. Where in your code is that user name used?

Comment: i'm using codeigniter to receive my data, for the username this is the problem, i use this line to put the username        conn.setRequestProperty("ref_name",ref_name);

Comment: But then you will have some php script to handle the upload isn't it? Please post the code. And react on my remark to read the response page.

Comment: I see that you save the uploaded image to file. But where do you save it to a database? Please format save_image_test_post so it is not on one line. Make it better readable for us.

Comment: i'm using a REST API so every function must be clear and contain post get or put. the image will be saved in a folder (images) and the name in database. i have no problem in saving image the problem was while sending another data with image

Comment: If you would just answer my questions and react to the point on my comments i could maybe help you. I did understand your problem already. You did not have to repeat that.

Comment: in my code ref_name refer to username